# How to make DB fields with no editor field persistent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a DB with below schema

```
    public partial class staging
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime createtime { get; set; }
            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            public string general { get; set; }
            public string articletype { get; set; }
        }
```

I have two views Create and Edit.
In Create View I'm updating general but the article type I'm updating from the controller and saving a DB as below

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Create(staging staging)
        {

            staging.createtime = DateTime.Now;
            staging.articletype = "Stage";
            try
            {
                db.stagings.Add(staging);
                db.SaveChanges();                
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                ViewData["error"] = "An error has occured: " + e.Message;
                return View(staging);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Details/" + staging.id);
        }
```

Now I have a edit field only for general.
So when I go to Edit View page I see that articletype has proper value but when it return in to HttpPost of "Edit" the articletype get set to NULL, think it's because I don't have an editor field for the same. And now when I update the DB from Edit Controller it gets set to NULL there as well.

So how can I make this value persistable across views? I will only update in Create event in controller but then I always want that value to be persisted.

Comment: [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: ASP.NET MVC returns and interprets information sent over HTTP requests.  The persisted data would have to be retrieved from a data source, such as a database or session variable, or posted back from a view back to a controller from the view to be persisted for you.

Comment: How do I post back the value from the view?? I view I have only editor fields like below

                <h3>Headline</h3>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.general)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.general)
                </div>

When I check Model.articletype that value is present in the view when when "staging" is returned to controller it gets set to NULL. And I don't know how to get the value into model => model.articletype

Comment: @user3917144, Use a view model containing only the properties you edit. In the post method, get the data model from the database based on the ID, then map your view model properties to the data model and save the data model.

Comment: you can add a `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.articletype)` inside your form tag but you can also just not update that field in your Edit action